# Netlify shows Page Not Found error with Flutter apps using GoRouter

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, netlify, flutter-routes, flutter-go-router

I have created an app using Flutter v3, and I am using GoRouter to handle all the routes. When I run the app on localhost, everything is working fine. But when I try to go to `/signIn` page after uploading it to Netlify, it shows a "Page Not Found" error.

URL: https://63406985ec088a30cd8c9de8--allmity-beta.netlify.app/

When you open the above URL, you will automatically be redirected to https://63406985ec088a30cd8c9de8--allmity-beta.netlify.app/signIn.

But when you go to https://63406985ec088a30cd8c9de8--allmity-beta.netlify.app/signIn directly, it will show the error.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the error by adding a 200 redirect rule in `netlify.toml` file to redirect all requests to `/`.

Here are a few helpful resources:

- https://answers.netlify.com/t/support-guide-direct-links-to-my-single-page-app-spa-dont-work/126
- https://www.netlify.com/blog/2019/01/16/redirect-rules-for-all-how-to-configure-redirects-for-your-static-site/